# How can I convert this event into a proper status command that loops its status to update when its added to a guild? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this event thats using on_ready, and i know that i probably shouldnt be using an on ready event for something that i want to update if it gets added a server or that a server gets a user who joins.

so here is what I mean: I want my bots status to change if it gets added to a server, and change when it gets removed. I also want it to update its membercount in the bots status if a server gets a new member. I know that rate limits are a thing so ill add a delay. I have this event that i need to be converted to a proper command but i dont know how, can you help me? (sorry for any spelling / grammar mistakes, its currently 3am as im writing this and i really just want to go to sleep)

Here is the event(I'm using cogs):

```
   @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Ready: {self.bot.user} | Servers: {len(self.bot.guilds)}')
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,name=f"tp!help v.{self.config.version} {len(self.bot.guilds)} Servers and {len(self.bot.users)} Users"))
```

I know this site isnt specifically for coding issues i just have no where else better to ask, and i know i need to read the docs and learn a bit more, but this is all i have left to fix / change in my bot then i can finally release it. if one of you could please just fix this for me that would be the best, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change presence in `on_ready` within your `Bot` or `Client`. Basically don't do anything in `on_ready` other than a print statement it's explicitly documented that it can be fired more than once.

Now to answer your question, you can use a simple [`loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/#discord.ext.tasks.loop) to update your presence every 15 seconds:

```
from discord.ext.tasks import loop


@loop(count=None, seconds=15)
async def presence_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await self.bot.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
            name=f"tp!help v.{self.config.version} {len(self.bot.guilds)} Servers and {len(self.bot.users)} Users"))


presence_loop.start()
client.run('token')
```

Inside a Class:

```
class ExampleClass(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.presence_loop.start()

    @loop(count=None, seconds=15)
    async def presence_loop(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                                                                 name=f"tp!help v.{self.config.version} {len(self.bot.guilds)} Servers and {len(self.bot.users)} Users"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed

Comment: Do you think you could edit it to fit inside a cog?